# JointJS and Extending Devs

Tags: jointjs

I'm trying to extend the joint.shapes.devs.Atomic model but get a "maximum call stack size exceeded" error.

This is apparently normal behavior for the devs module.  ( see the following link: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jointjs/md5s_fKPl_M ).

I was wondering if there is a way to work around this?  Would it be better to just edit the devs module directly?  The solution in the above link won't work for me, since I'll need to be able to convert the data into JSON.

**Edit**

I've made my own object based on the devs model.  I can extend this model as I need to, but I still don't like this as a solution. I don't think it offers the same kind of flexibility with extending as I was looking for.  If anyone has a better option please let me know.